# Ширина столбцов JTable

Tags: java, jtable

Имеется код

```
JFrame jFrame=new JFrame();
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jFrame.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    DefaultTableModel dtm=new DefaultTableModel(5,4);
    JTable jTable=new JTable(dtm);
    jFrame.add(jTable);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Подскажите каким образом можно установить ширину столбцов например так 1-ый 10%, 2-ой 50%, 3-ий и 4-ый по 20%

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

```
 jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn( 0 ).setWidth( 20 );
```

Только размеры ставятся в абсолютных размерах.

Для задания размеров в диапазоне используйте минимальное и максимальное значение например:

```
 TableColumn col = jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn( 0 );
 col.setMinWidth(20);
 col.setMaxWidth(50);
```

для пересчета размеров при изменении размера таблицы, повесьте слушатель на таблицу, например так

```
 jTable.addPropertyChangeListener( new PropertyChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void propertyChange( PropertyChangeEvent evt ){
            if( evt.getPropertyName().equals( "size" ) ){
                jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn( 0 ).setWidth( (int)(jTable.getWidth() * 0.1) );
                ...
            }
        }
 } );
```

Comment: В том то и дело, что абсолютные размеры не подходят, т.к. при смене устройства таблица ломается.

Comment: устанавливайте диапазон, тогда размеры столбцов будут растягиваться/сужаться в заданном диапазоне

Comment: Вся таблица да... Но мне необходимо сохранить пропорции ширины столбцов.

Comment: тогда можете повесить слушатель на изменение размеров таблицы, и каждый раз под размер пересчитывать ширину колонок

Comment: добавил пример в ответ

Comment: Что бы работал getWidth необходимо чтобы таблица уже была нарисована, я могу как нибудь задать пропорции до того как она будет создана?

Comment: задайте таблице preferedSize. Если таблица еще не нарисована то считывайте preferedSize